# Не могу понять реализацию на Scala функции union

Tags: scala

Привет. Есть код некой рекурсивной функции `union` в классе `NonEmpty`, которая обьеденяет два binary search дерева в одно. Было бы здорово если кому то не составило труда подробно (желательно на примере) пояснить, как она работает. Для лучшего понимания добавлю класс, в котором есть интерестна мне ф-я.

```
abstract class TweetSet {
  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet
  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet
}

class Empty extends TweetSet {
  override def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = that
  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = new NonEmpty(tweet, new Empty, new Empty)
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {
  override def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =
    (left union (right union that)).incl(elem)

  def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
    if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this
  }
}
```

Comment: Привет, мне кажется в данной реализации есть ошибка: union вызываемый на NonEmpty, будет рекурсивно спускаться сначала в правый конец дерева, затем, когда дойдет до Empty сработает Empty.union: затем он поднимется на уровень выше и выполнить тоже с левым поддеревом:  (right Empty.union that) -> that тогда (left NonEmpty.union that). Посмотри вот эту реализацию, может здесь нет ошибки: https://gist.github.com/rbaron/8ca634b2aee69b3262ff, там метод NonEmpty.union реализован иначе. incl применяется на результат (right union that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При объединении коллекций возможны 2 случая: объединение с пустой коллекцией (даст 1ю коллекцию) и с не пустой.

Для объяснения процесса объединения с непустой коллекцией, рассмотрим метод incl(x: Tweet). Каждый его вызов рекурсивно перестраивает левое или правое поддерево, в зависимости от аргумента.

Метод union(that: TweetSet) рекурсивно объединяет одно из поддеревьев текущего дерева с деревом that, затем другое поддерево также объединяет с полученным результатом, и наконец, добавляет корень к полученному дереву.

Для пояснения на примере, можно добавить методы визуализации результата.

```
class Tweet(val text: String)
class Empty extends TweetSet {
  ....
  override def toString = "."
}
class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {
  override def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    val res = (left union (right union that)).incl(elem)
    println(s"union ${this} and ${that} is " + res)
    res
  }
  ...
  override def toString = "{" + left + "," + right + "}" 
}
```

Далее сам код тестирования:

```
object ts {
val emp = new Empty                       //> emp  : Empty = .
def generTweet = new Tweet(scala.util.Random.nextString(10))
                                              //> generTweet: => Tweet
def generTweets(n: Int) = for (i <- 0 until n) yield generTweet
                                              //> generTweets: (n: Int)scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Tweet]
def generTweetSet(n: Int, acc: TweetSet = new Empty): TweetSet =
    if (n == 0) acc
    else generTweetSet(n-1, acc.incl(generTweet))
                                              //> generTweetSet: (n: Int, acc: TweetSet)TweetSet

val nonEmpty1 = generTweetSet(1)          //> nonEmpty1  : TweetSet = {.,.}
val nonEmpty2 = generTweetSet(1)          //> nonEmpty2  : TweetSet = {.,.}
nonEmpty1 union nonEmpty2                 //> union {.,.} and {.,.} is {.,{.,.}}
                                              //| res0: TweetSet = {.,{.,.}}

val nonEmpty3 = generTweetSet(2)          //> nonEmpty3  : TweetSet = {{.,.},.}
nonEmpty1 union nonEmpty3                 //> union {.,.} and {{.,.},.} is {{.,.},{.,.}}
                                              //| res1: TweetSet = {{.,.},{.,.}}
nonEmpty3 union nonEmpty1                       //> union {.,.} and {.,.} is {{.,.},.}
                                              //| union {{.,.},.} and {.,.} is {{.,{.,.}},.}
                                              //| res2: TweetSet = {{.,{.,.}},.}
val nonEmpty4 = generTweetSet(2)                //> nonEmpty4  : TweetSet = {.,{.,.}}
nonEmpty3 union nonEmpty4                       //> union {.,.} and {.,{.,.}} is {.,{{.,.},.}}
                                              //| union {{.,.},.} and {.,{.,.}} is {.,{{.,{.,.}},.}}
                                              //| res3: TweetSet = {.,{{.,{.,.}},.}}
}
```